# Writing Unit Test for XSRF Token in Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, http-headers, token

Within my service class, I've written a getHttpOptions method for http headers, but I'm having some difficulty testing a branch for an if statement that sets the headers if XSRF TOKEN is not null. here's the  the service :

```
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor,
  ) {}


getProductResponse(): Observable<ProductDetails[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ProductDetails[]>(
      endpointKeys.endpoints.BASE_PATH + endpointKeys.endpoints.PRODUCT_DETAILS_PAGE,
      this.getHttpOptions(),
    );
  }

getHttpOptions(): {} {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    const XSRF_TOKEN = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
    if (XSRF_TOKEN !== null) { //<---- branch not covered in test coverage
      headers = headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', XSRF_TOKEN);
    }
    return {
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials: true,
    };
  }
}
```

In my spec file here's what i tried:

```
  it('should make a call to get Product Details Info', () => {

  let productResponse :  ProductDetails;//this is an interface

    service
      .getProductDetails()
      .subscribe((response: ProductDetails[]) =>
        expect(response).toEqual(productResponse),
      );

    const request = httpTestingController.expectOne((req) =>
      req.url.includes('user/product'),//just an endpoint for the url
    );
    expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  });
```

I fixed an error i had but it doesnt test the branch I want for the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to `spyOn` `HttpXsrfTokenExtractor`'s `getToken` method to return not `null`. Something like this:

```
it('should make a call to get Product Details Info', () => {

  let productResponse :  ProductDetails;//this is an interface
  // !! Get a handle on HttpXsrfTokenExtractor
  let tokenExtractor = TestBed.inject(HttpXsrfTokenExtractor);
  // !! Spy on it and make it return a non null value.
  spyOn(tokenExtractor, 'getToken').and.returnValue('MY_AWESOME_TOKEN');

    service
      .getProductDetails()
      .subscribe((response: ProductDetails[]) =>
        expect(response).toEqual(productResponse),
      );

    const request = httpTestingController.expectOne((req) =>
      req.url.includes('user/product'),//just an endpoint for the url
    );
    expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  });
```